# Cognos Reprompt button auto runs report

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have a report that has a reprompt button on the prompt page, which is all cascading prompts, and then a back button on the report page that brings you back to the prompt page. So the idea is you can run the report go back to the prompt page from the report and then select new prompt values, reprompt and rerun the report. The problem is when it runs the first time and you go back to the prompt page and then select new values in the prompt and hit the reprompt button the report automatically runs instead of reprompting and cascading. Not only does it automatically run but it runs the first run done not with the new prompts selected. Any ideas on how i can get this to work properly?

Comment: I assume *auto-submit* is *yes* for your prompts to allow cascading automatically.  Controlling prompting can be tricky in this scenario.  You may need to replace the *Finish* button with Javascript and a hidden, required, textbox prompt that is blank when the prompt page loads.

Lots of assuming.  Can you reproduce the problem from the samples and publish the report spec?

Why the *Back* button on the report?  The *Run* button in the toolbar at the top already does that.

Comment: its not an autosubmit. its a Reprompt button the user clicks after they select their prompts. Then they hit finish to run the report. Javascript was added where you click on a picture it brings you back to the prompt page. Then they want to check different prompts and hit reprompt again and then finish to run the report. The problem is they select new parameters and hit reprompt and the report automatically runs instead of wait for the user to select finish.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion, try copying and pasting the prompt from the prompt page onto the top of the report page

Have a radio button (or some simple prompt) that can set a parameter to hide/show the report.  Select the content and set the property to render

This way a user can change the prompt values and avoid re-running the report
(and the user does not have to go back to the prompt page)